# Operational amplifier for higher slew rate

Tags: operational-amplifier, cmos, slew-rate

what are the possible ways to improve slew rate of an operational amplifier in CMOS technology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What defines the SlewRate? dv/dt = I/C

Many opamps have an internally-compensated "BIG CAP" approach.
Examine the schematic of the Fairchild UA709, find its several Rs and Cs that provide the stabilization, and understand that.

Then ask yourself once again ----- what defines the SlewRate?

Its still working with Q = C * V, differentiated and assuming C is constant, to arrive at dV/dT = I/C.